# How To Tell If A File Has Completed Posting On A Drive

Tags: windows

I have some code that tells me whether a file exists on a drive or not, but not whether that file has completed posting to the directory its being placed in. So, when I use code that tells me if it exists and what size it is, it will tell me it exists and gives me a particular size, but upon running it the second time, I get a different file size answer as the file is still posting and data is being posted to it, causing it to grow in size.

So, is there anyway to tell if a file has completed posting? Any properties of the file I can use. Also note, someone suggested using VBA with the Windows API. I did a check on the web, but there doesn't appear to be anything specific to my needs. Any help is appreciated!

I'm using VBA and here is the code I have that gives me the data I mentioned above. Also, At this time, I do not know what processes are used by the dept. that generates these files. Hopefully I won't need to know if there is a way to get what I need without that info! Thanks for any assistance!

```
Public Sub sub_chk_files2()

    Dim obj_fs As Object
    Dim obj_folder As Object
    Dim obj_files As Object
    Dim obj_f1 As Object
    Dim str_fp As String
    Dim str_fqfp As String
    Dim int_count_files As Integer
    Dim str_import_file_name As String
    Dim lng_file_size As Long

    str_fp = "C:\01_reporting\"

    Set obj_fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set obj_folder = obj_fs.getfolder(str_fp)
    Set obj_files = obj_folder.files

    For Each obj_f1 In obj_files


        If obj_f1.Name = "data2.csv" Then

            str_import_file_name = obj_f1.Name
            str_fqfp = str_fp & str_import_file_name
            lng_file_size = FileLen(str_fqfp) / 1000

            MsgBox "File " & str_import_file_name & " was created on " & obj_f1.DateCreated & " File size = " & lng_file_size & " File Modified on " & obj_f1.DatelastModified

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't find an answer on Google because you're using unusual words.

Files don't "post" to disk. Processes write to files.

The easiest way to find out if another process is writing to it is by getting exclusive write access. Windows has mandatory locking. So, `CreateFile(..., GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, )` will not succeed if another process is writing, but it can succeed if another process is just reading.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Another group actually runs a process that writes to these files. What I want to do is create a process of my own that looks at these files to see if they are done being written to. btw, I don't have any rights/permissions to any of what they are doing an cannot acquire them..

Comment: Well, then this solution will probably work. Of course, if that other process writes to file, then stops, closes the file, and a minute later reopens it to write more, then you might have an issue. But that's unavoidable. You can't predict what the other process will do, this just checks what the other process is doing right now.